# -static-libstdc++: undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'

Tags: c++, gcc

I use `-static-libstdc++` to link executable with static c++ std lib. (because libstdc++.so.6 may be different in CI machine and production environment.)

link result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../Common/lib/libconfig_sdk.a(config_service_sdk.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
//usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but the symbol is found in C++ so:

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | egrep GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | egrep _ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE 
_ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE
$ nm ../Common/lib/libconfig_sdk.a | grep _ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE
                 U _ZTVNSt13__future_base11_State_baseE
```

I search in Google but get little information. How to solve the link problem?